# Create folder remotely and Copy files

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a folder (if it does not exists on the server) using **"powershell on target machine"** task in **Azure Pipeline** and then copy files over from share location to the new folder created. Below is the powershell script that i am using:

```
    $DeployDB = "\\$(ServerName)\DeployDB"

     if(Test-Path $DeployDB){
         Write-Host "Path Exists!!"
     }else{
        New-Item "c:\DeployDB" -ItemType Directory
        New-SmbShare -Name DeployDB -Path C:\DeployDB | Grant-SmbShareAccess -AccountName Everyone -AccessRight Full -Force

    $acl = Get-Acl "c:\DeployDB"
    $AccessRule1 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone","FullControl","Allow")
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule1)
    Set-Acl "c:\DeployDB" $acl 
}
Copy-Item -Path \\MyServer\Data\** -Destination c:\DeployDB -Recurse -Force -verbose
```

`$ServerName` is sent as an input when queuing the build.

Above script successfully creates the file and share the same with right permissions but for some reason it does not copy over the files from share location to the new folder created. Same copy command works fine if i run it alone from powershell directly. The odd part is there are no errors when the step completes. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: After 30 second glance, your 1st line is missing a $ inside the $().  Your line should be `$DeployDB = "\\$ServerName\DeployDB"` or `$DeployDB = "\\$($ServerName)\DeployDB"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the solution in thread [Azure DevOps Pipeline - Power shell script , Copy Files using Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911755/azure-devops-pipeline-power-shell-script-copy-files-using-variables), by adding new variable for the source folder and destination folder:

```
Copy-Item $($sourcefolder) -Destination $($destination)
```

Or you can just add [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy the files.

Comment: used the "Windows Machine File Copy task" for some reason the copy-item wont work at all. Thanks